# Cannot access field in member method in JavaScript when use Class feature of ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I try to use the feature Class in ES6. I initialize a object A which has a field B and member function C, but when I try to access B in C, console said C is undefined. code shown in below.

A code block

```
extension = new IcpSdkExtensionBase();
device = new IcpSdkDeviceBase();
eventsBack = new IcpSdkEventsBackBase();
proxy = new IcpProxy(device, eventsBack, extension, 'ws://127.0.0.1:56789/IcpConsole');

function login() {
    console.log(eventsBack);
    eventsBack.OnUnifiedLogoutResult(0, 0, 0);   
}
```

B code block

```
'use strict';

class IcpSdkEventsBackBase {


    constructor(eventsBacks, name) {
        this.eventsBacks = [];
        if (arguments.length === 0) {
            console.log(this);
            return this;
        }

        for (let key in arguments) {
            if (!(arguments.hasOwnProperty(key))) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!(arguments[key] instanceof IcpSdkEventsBackBase)) {
                continue;
            }
            this.eventsBacks.add(arguments[key]);
        }
        return this;

    }


    OnUnifiedLogoutResult(callId, flag, errorCode) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(typeof (this));      
        console.log(this.eventsBacks);
        this.eventsBacks.forEach(p => {
           p.OnUnifiedLogoutResult(callId, flag, errorCode);
    });
}
```

}

And in Chrome Console, A code block log like below, which prove that eventsBack is not undefined.

```
IcpSdkEventsBackBase {eventsBacks: Array(0)}
```

But B code block log like below

```
    undefined
    undefined
    icp-sdk-events-back-base.js:37 undefined
    icp-sdk-events-back-base.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventsBacks' of undefined
        at OnUnifiedLogoutResult (icp-sdk-events-back-base.js:38)
        at IcpSdkEventsBackBase.<anonymous> (icp-proxy.js:83)
        at login (icp-console-demo.js:11)
        at HTMLInputElement.onclick (icp-console-demo.html:29)
```

It's weird in log of B code block. Because I have already new an object, and in A block it 
 logs correctly, But in B code block, it said **this**  is undefined.

Comment: class IcpSdkEventsBackBase looks good. It has to do something with where class instance is created.

Comment: finally,I found the problem.this code  fragment

proxy = new IcpProxy(device, eventsBack, extension, 'ws://127.0.0.1:56789/IcpConsole');

this line I use the dynamic proxy which I achieve it  through Aspect, but it's wrong , It will lead the method lose it's original object, So I change the proxy to use Proxy in ES6. It's solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally,I found the problem.
this code fragment 
`proxy = new IcpProxy(device, eventsBack, extension, 'ws://127.0.0.1:56789/IcpConsole');`

this line I use the dynamic proxy which I achieve it through Aspect, but it's wrong , It will lead the method lose it's original object, So I change the proxy to use Proxy in ES6. It's solved